# Clicking link on edge will enable popup only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on a .asp page. where users have a link in that page and if they happen to be using edge browser and they happen to click on that link a popup window will show up, disabling the background and letting them know that this application is not supported in edge browser, then they should be able to close the popup window but the link should not proceed but it should not be disabled, and if they happen to be using other browsers then they should be able to proceed and click on the link.Is there a way with javascript to accomplish this?

Comment: That seems like a pretty lame thing to do to an Edge user. Why do you want to accomplish this?

Comment: You just need to accurately detect the browser. Look for [Platform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/platform) which I found to be easy to use and accurate. Then, it is simple JS to open a modal.

Comment: @ceejayoz: OP wants to inform users that the rest of his application seems to be proven uncompatible (for some reason) with Edge. There is nothing wrong in that question.

Comment: But, for sure... That should be the "mitigation plan" while the Edge bug fix is beeing worked on... ;)